# Column of same width in TableLayout, *programmatically*

Tags: android, android-layout

I read on SO that in order to obtain a tablelayout where each column has the same width, you can set `android:width="0dp"` and `android:weight="1"` as layout parameter and it works.
I would obtain the same result, but programmatically, so I tried this chunk of code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_score, container, false);

    TableRow row = (TableRow)rootView.findViewById(R.id.playerRow);
    for (Player p : game.getPlayers()) {
        TextView t = new TextView(rootView.getContext());
        t.setText(p.getName());
        row.addView(t, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(0, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
        // with the previuos line of code, nothing is showed
        // instead this work: row.addView(t) , but each column doesn't take the maximum width (as I would)

    }

    return rootView;
}
```

But as explained in comment, it doesn't work as expected.
I can't get what I am missing.

Comment: Try this: `row.addView(t, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(parent.getWidth()/numColumns, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0));` where numColumns == number of columns in your table

Comment: Same result. I tried `row.addView(t, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(row.getWidth()/game.getPlayers().size(), TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));`, nothing changed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an error in my code, LayoutParams is the wrong class, I should have used `TableRow.LayoutParams` instead of `TableLayout.LayoutParams`, so:

```
row.addView(t, new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
```

works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this one, especially if you wish to set margins among table cells.

```
TableRow.LayoutParams tableRowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1f);
tableRowParams.setMargins(5,5,5,5);
row.addView(t, tableRowParams);
```

For uniform column distribution must add `android:stretchColumns="*"` in `TableLayout` in your xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <!-- 2 columns -->
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:text="Column 1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:text="Column 2" />
    </TableRow>

    <!-- edittext span 2 column -->
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:text="Column 1 &amp; 2" />
    </TableRow>

    <!-- just draw a red line -->
    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    <!-- 3 columns -->
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:text="Column 1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:text="Column 2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:text="Column 3" />
    </TableRow>

    <!-- display this button in 3rd column via layout_column(zero based) -->
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:text="Column 3" />
    </TableRow>

    <!-- display this button in 2nd column via layout_column(zero based) -->
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="Column 2" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do it programmatically

Comment: you can follow 1. http://puneetaggarwal.in/android/android-tablelayout-programatically/ or 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226168/android-tablelayout-programatically

Comment: any questions about above links?

Comment: I just had time to see it, they are not useful for me, because I already know how to create a TableLayout programmatically, my problems is that the code above doesn't work or doesn't show column of the same width