# Programatically Added EditText does not has the match_parent width property set

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I'm running the following code within a for loop.

```
TableRow r1 = new TableRow(this);
r1 .setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

TextView editLabel = new TextView(this);
editLabel.setText("Label");
EditText editText = new EditText(this);
editText.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
editText.setMaxLines(1);

r1.addView(editLabel);
r1.addView(editText);
tableLayout1.addView(r1);
```

The rows are added to the TableLayout but the EditText does not seem to have the match_parent property in effect for layout_width. The table layout that I use is

```
<TableLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:stretchColumns="0"
android:shrinkColumns="1"
android:id="@+id/attibutesLayout">
</TableLayout>
```

The edittext seems to have zero width and keeps increasing as I input data. I want the edittext to have constant width to fit inside the column.

Comment: follow this http://huuah.com/using-tablelayout-on-android/   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226168/android-tablelayout-programatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code

```
 TableRow r1 = new TableRow(this);
    r1 .setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    final float scale = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    TextView editLabel = new TextView(this);
    editLabel.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,(int) (1 * scale + 0.5f)));
    editLabel.setText("Label");
    EditText editText = new EditText(this);
    editText.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,(int) (1 * scale + 0.5f)));
    editText.setMaxLines(1);
    r1.addView(editLabel);
    r1.addView(editText);
    tableLayout1.addView(r1);
```

and your xml is same

```
<TableLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:stretchColumns="0"
android:shrinkColumns="1"
android:id="@+id/attibutesLayout">
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: If I make stretch columns as "1" then the width will not be a constant. The width will grow as I type in more text

Comment: then you have to set each View’s layout_width equal to 0 and weight to 1 for your tablerow elements

Comment: to set the width and weight programmatically use my update answer

Answer (score 0):

You set wrong value for `TableLayout stretchColumns`, change it to 1 should solve your problem. Use the following layout and have a try:

```
<TableLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:stretchColumns="1"
android:shrinkColumns="1"
android:id="@+id/attibutesLayout">
</TableLayout>
```